# High Frequency Blinking LED

Tags: led, frequency, high-frequency, led-driver, blink

I need to get an LED blinking at in the 1-5Khz range.  I will use a photo detector to sense the blink rate to identify a drone.

The drone will be passing though a hoop about 1 foot from the sensor.

Think of it as being similar to a short distance, Li-Fi, visible light communications, PHY layer design.

Ideally the LED needs to remain as bright as possible and remain at a constant blink speed even as the battery discharges.

Weight is an important criteria for this design, so every gram possible needs to be shaven from the circuit.

On-board voltage is 3.7volts.

Comment: Please tell us what you are trying to do. This seems likely to be an xy question, where you may have settled on an inappropriate approach to an underlying problem. Why, for instance, do you need MHz speeds? Why not KHz? With that said, MHz modulation of LEDs is getting into "hard" country, and detecting such an LED even harder. Or have you given that any thought?

Comment: I'd use an ATTiny85 (8 pin SOIC) using the internal clock and running directly off your Li-Ion battery. A few lines of assembler could do the job.

Comment: So, you want someone to design you a circuit

Comment: *Gram wants to be shaved* I'm quite sure Gram wants to keep his beard, he's very proud of it.

Comment: Umm  Let me update that and correct my Mhz to Khz

Comment: Explain **why** you need to make the LED blink at 1 - 5 kHz.

Comment: because I want to be able to identify an object that will only be in view for a very short time. And I want to do so with out adding extra weight to the drone. The drone already has LED's around it for orientation help. By blinking them at a fast rate I am hoping to get identification with out adding additional systems / weight.

Comment: And because it will be sensed as it moves past the sensor it needs to blink fast enough that enough flashes can be detected to identify between drones.

Comment: The optical design seems to be under-defined/developed to make this a serious question. how about several IR emitters with omni directional output with results when interrogated.

Comment: Well yes because if it was fully developed then it would not be a question would it, it would be a completed project! The question was "How to make a LED flash at Khz speeds taking in to consideration weight" I was not asking for how to detect it or why I want to do it. None of that is needed to provide an answer to the question.

Comment: Olin below seemed to have no problems giving a correct, helpful and useful answer based on the question.

Comment: You might be able to add a blinking routine to your drones MCU. So the only extra weight will be of the LED.

Comment: Tony, because the drone currently weighs <50g so any extra weight is unwanted. IT already has 4 constantly lite LED's, so swapping these to blinking or adding a oscillating circuit in between power source and LED avoids adding extra systems and weight to the drone. Something IR emitters would. The other options are adding reflective strips, object detection using video camera. For larger drones we use IR emitters and RFID, but it is all to bulky for micro drone. so its about keeping the weight of the drone. optical detection around if needed to detect the flashing LED.

Comment: Wesley, I haven't seen any FC that you can do any fine control with LED blinking, maybe able to "hack" them but its generally either blink / not blink. some flight controllers have transponders built in (IR and RF) but not for the micro drones sizes.

Comment: @DevilWAH  I recall learning how to get designs right the first time by considering all the parameters that can cause system failure before choosing a design.  Daylight blocking, and detection method ought to be considered.  A VCO or voltage controlled one shot can change the frequency of your existing LEDs over a wide range then it needs to be scaled from 2.9 to 3.7V for battery range, although <3.5V is more important.  for only a few grams.

Comment: Tony this is not even at the design phase yet :) It's is also not the only idea I have, just one of many I am fact finding for. I have ideas for daylight blocking and detection. at the moment I am researching different methods I could used that could be mounted on the drone and don't add much weight. Flashing LED, Reflective strip/ LED color/ NFC / NRF24 / IR emmiter, etc Once I have ordered in best to worse from drone point of view I will look at the complexities of the remote sensor, I know i can sense a khz flashing light, Asking all the questions before i put design togather.

Comment: Again not a design but an idea, my thought process is that Drone will pass though a ring, which will have a number of photo diode / transistors set set around the edge pointing to the middle releases in to a trough to cut out light and give them a narrow field of view across to the other edge of the ring.  also the bottom of the trough will be aligned with a reflective coating. As the drone passes through the ring the light will reflect round so all diaos see it (error correction for external light and drone orientation) and it might not be drone blinks a consent rate but a pattern.

Answer (score 6):

Especially considering size and weight, I'd use a PIC 10F200 microcontroller.  It has a oscillator built in, and needs no other components other than a bypass cap to drive a LED.  It can also run from a reasonably wide voltage range, including 3.7 V.

The internal oscillator is good to a few percent.  The instruction cycle rate is 1 MHz driven by that oscillator.  At 1-5 kHz, you have a minimum of 200 cycles per blink period, or 100 cycles per blink phase.  That's plenty to do a little counting to decide when to toggle the LED state.

The output pins can source or sink a few mA, and you can gang three of them together to get more current capability to drive the LED directly with a resistor in series to set the current.

Comment: Cheers that great idea, i was thinking of using timers or oscillating circuits. Never thought of a micro controller and this will give plenty accurate enough rates for what i am planning. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty design using a ZSCT1555 CMOS timer IC as a VCO and PWM to change not only the duty cycle of color from Yellow to Red with battery voltage but also the frequency up to a 2:1 range for an input voltage range of 3.6 to 3.3V  .

I chose ~2kHz high to 4kHz when low Vbat and simulated it here with [**Falstad**](http://ZSCT1555), but you may want a slower rate.  The output driver toggles between 2 of the 4 existing LEDs changed to Red/Yellow and duty cycle of Red increases as Vbat drops.

There are an infinite number of variations of this including Red Only when below a certain threshold.  The 2V zener is actually another LED.

I used a 10Hz triangle wave to simulate Vbat from 3.6 to 3V but it works beyond this range.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Once you started actually talking about your problem, it became clear that you were indeed asking an xy question. The question you really want answered, is "How can I identify a drone by blinking its orientation lights?" or even better, "I'd like to identify a drone by blinking its orientation lights. What should I be thinking about?". Although the latter is a bit vague, I agree.

With that in mind, it's clear that blinking the orientation lights at 1 to 5 kHz will not do you any good. If you're looking at it with your eyes, kHz is way beyond visual fusion rate, so there's no way your eye can distinguish between drones with different flash rates. If you're looking at it with a camera, 1 to 5 kHz is far beyond the frame rate you'll get with any reasonable camera. To identify a 5 kHz flash rate from camera footage requires a minimum of 10,000 frames per second, and that is hardly standard kit.

All things considered, it would seem your best bet is to point a telescope at it with a very high-sensitivity detector and a frequency detection circuit.  Such a detector would require a very narrow bandpass filter at the LED wavelength.

So, rather than insisting that what you want to know is how to flash an LED, you need to start thinking about just exactly what you want to do from a system viewpoint, and determine if you CAN identify a drone by flashing its LEDs. Only after you've done your system calculations should you start worrying about how to do it.

Comment: No because the drone will be passing though a hoop about 1 foot from the sensor and I already know that there are IR transponders on drones out there that work on this exact method. With a science degree (Zoology) I am well aware of the capabilits on the human eye, and having worked with Fiber optics for the last 15 years (flashing lights) and more recent developments in Li-Fi i know there are ways of sensing flashing lights well in to the Mhz range over many meters.

Comment: @DevilWAH You might have thought to put that in your original post. I was wondering how far away the LEDs would be from the detector.  Now it all makes sense.  Very simple, I like that.